# How to get a list of system shortcuts and user defined shortcuts(if any) in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext

On connecting an External Keyboard to my Android device I'm able to use keyboard shortcuts like ctrl+C, ctrl+V, etc in an EditText field. Is there any Android API to get a list of all the keyboard shortcuts that the Android OS provides?

Answer (score 1):

afaik there is no API for that, but there is an official list, extended in released few days ago Android 14 version. [HERE](https://www.phonearena.com/news/android-14-physical-keyboard-shortcuts_id147672) you can find list and some options how to find those

Comment: The list you mentioned has only new shortcuts, could please add the link to the official list containing all shortcuts, I'm not able to find that.

Comment: sadly don't have any link for official doc, but you can connect physical keyboard and then pick Settings -> System -> Keyboard -> Physical keyboard, there you can find whole list of shortcuts (till Android 13 it contains 13 elements, Android 14 adds ~20, [source](https://www.androidpolice.com/android-14-physical-keyboard-shortcuts-list/))

Comment: At least on the Android phone I have (Samsung A13) this path does not lead to a list of keyboard shortcuts :-( -- So YMMV